# Ошибка "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_value' in base 'Nil'." в GodotEngine

Tags: godot

Работаю в GodotEngine, пытаюсь сделать взаимодействие с NPC через Dialogic. Но при каждой попытке выдаёт ошибку:
`Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'get_value' in base 'Nil'.`

и переправляет меня на строку в скрипте

`var anchor = current_theme.get_value('box', 'anchor', 9)`

В чём может быть проблема?

код NPC:

```
func _input(event):
if event.is_action_pressed("взаимодействие") and active:
    get_tree().paused = true
    var dialog = Dialogic.start("/TALK1")
    dialog.pause_mode = Node.PAUSE_MODE_PROCESS
    dialog.connect("timeline_end", self, "unpause")
    add_child(dialog)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашёл: нужно во вкладке Dialogic установить тему, и всё заработает; код означает что тема не задана, поэтому движок не может показать диалоговое окно. –